# Unique combination/product of two columns from multiple lists in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

**How can I get every *possible unique combination* of values from multiple lists?**

***Input:***

```
list_1 = ['copper', 'auroch', 'mirror']
list_2 = ['garland', 'clover', 'cocoahollow']
list_3 = ['garland', 'seraph', 'yolkwing']
list_4 = ['garland', 'clover', 'cocoahollow']
list_5 = ['riftwater', 'mothersday', 'snowsquall']
```

***Expected Output:***

```
unique_combination = [('copper', 'garland'), ('copper', 'clover'), ('copper', 'cocoahollow'), ('copper', 'seraph'), ('copper', 'yolkwing'), ('copper', 'riftwater'), ('copper', 'mothersday'), ('copper', 'snowsquall'), ('garland', 'auroch'), ('garland', 'mirror'), ('garland', 'garland'), ('garland', 'seraph'), ('garland', 'yolkwing'),('garland', 'clover'), ('garland', 'cocoahollow') ........]
```

---

I know this has huge complexity and it's not at all optimal. But at least this is producing the desired output.

```
list_1 = ['copper', 'auroch', 'mirror']
list_2 = ['garland', 'clover', 'cocoahollow']
list_3 = ['garland', 'seraph', 'yolkwing']
list_4 = ['garland', 'clover', 'cocoahollow']
list_5 = ['riftwater', 'mothersday', 'snowsquall']

unique_combination = []


def put_in_unique_combination_list(input_parent_1, input_parent_2, unique_combination):
    if (input_parent_1, input_parent_2) not in unique_combination or (
            input_parent_2, input_parent_1) not in unique_combination:
        unique_combination.append((input_parent_1, input_parent_2))
    return unique_combination


for each_parent1_list, each_parent2_lists in [
    (list_1, [list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5]),
    (list_2, [list_3, list_4, list_5]),
    (list_3, [list_4, list_5]),
    (list_4, [list_5])]:
    for each_item_in_parent1_list in each_parent1_list:
        parent_1 = each_item_in_parent1_list
        for each_parent2_list in each_parent2_lists:
            for each_item_in_parent2_list in each_parent2_list:
                parent_2 = each_item_in_parent2_list
                unique_combination = put_in_unique_combination_list(parent_1, parent_2, unique_combination)

print(unique_combination)
```

Please help me to write it in the proper way.

Comment: You show `('copper', 'cocoahollow')` twice, is this correct? Also, would `('garland', 'garland')` be included (for example, as a combination from `list_2` and `list_3`), and if not what is the reason? Finally, you seem to skip `('garland', 'clover')` with `garland` from `list_2` and `clover` from `list_4`; is this intentional?

Comment: Thanks @constantstranger for noticing this, I updated the `unique_combination` list now.

Comment: Does the order of the `unique_combination` list matter?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. The output however differs to your working solution which includes elements like `('auroch', 'clover')` twice due to `put_in_unique_combination_list` using and `or` when checking for tuple uniqueness.

---

`config` sets up the mapping of `(list_n, {list_n + 1, ...]}` and `chain` is used to flatten the other lists into a single iterable.

`frozenset` just makes each item in the group unique.

```py
from itertools import chain, product

all_lists = [
    ['copper', 'auroch', 'mirror'],
    ['garland', 'clover', 'cocoahollow'],
    ['garland', 'seraph', 'yolkwing'],
    ['garland', 'clover', 'cocoahollow'],
    ['riftwater', 'mothersday', 'snowsquall']
]

unique_combination = set()

config = [
    (all_lists[i], frozenset(chain.from_iterable(all_lists[i+1:])))
    for i in range(len(all_lists) - 1)
]

for lst, others in config:
    for pair in product(lst, others):
        # Remove this is (x,y) and (y,x) is allowed
        if pair not in unique_combination and (pair[1], pair[0]) not in unique_combination:
            unique_combination.add(pair)

# Output
from pprint import pprint
pprint(sorted(unique_combination))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try product from itertools and convert tuples to set(for uniqueness) and then convert back to tuple:

```
from itertools import product


list_1 = ['copper', 'auroch', 'mirror']
list_2 = ['garland', 'clover', 'cocoahollow']
list_3 = ['garland', 'seraph', 'yolkwing']
list_4 = ['garland', 'clover', 'cocoahollow']
list_5 = ['riftwater', 'mothersday', 'snowsquall']

unique_combination = list(product(list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5))
unique_combination = list(map(lambda x: set(x), unique_combination))
unique_combination = list(map(lambda x: tuple(x), unique_combination))
print(unique_combination)
```

Comment: Hey Hamed thanks for your answer, But it is not proper as it generates `[('garland', 'riftwater', 'copper'), ('garland', 'mothersday', 'copper'),...]` output which doesn't match with the desired output. Unfortunately, I can't take this answer but thanks again for answering.